# Preselect dropdown option during while loop based on value

Tags: php, mysql, loops, select, while-loop

I have two tables a ***Workorder*** table that has a column in it called **status_id** it lets me know the status of the order if its untouched, in progress, or finished. It just holding the numerical value of the status.

[image: workorder table]

I have a second table named ***Status*** that has a matching **status_id** and the text of the status.

[image: status table]

I have a dropdown while loop that pulls the Status table and echos it out.

I am trying to make it select the dropdown option that is associated with the workorder table status.

```
<select name="status" class="form-control input-default" required>
<option selected disabled>Status</option>       
<?php
$status_sql = "SELECT * FROM STATUS";   
$result_status = $conn->query($status_sql);
while ($status_row = $result_status->fetch_assoc()) {
$status_id   = $status_row['status_id'];
$status_name = $status_row['status_text'];
//select status based on value in workorder row
$select_status = (1 == 1)? 'selected="selected"':'';
echo '<option value="' . $status_id . '" '.$select_status.'>'.$status_name . '</option>';   
}
?>
</select>
```

I am using this php code as an is equal to to echo the selected html tag

I am trying to combine two tables into one

```
$sql = "SELECT *, w.status_id as wid, s.status_id as sid 
FROM WORKORDER w 
INNER JOIN STATUS s 
ON w.status_id = s.status_id
";
```

and then turning the statement into this

```
$select_status = ( $status_row['sid'] == $status_id  = $status_row['status_id'])? 'selected="selected"':'';
```

I am unable to figure it out if someone can please help me out. Thank you!

Comment: Tip: NEVER use `SELECT *`

Comment: **1** does the query return what you expect it to return?  **2** in the example tables in your question, status_id == 2, but there is no status_id == 2 in the **Status** table.  **3** your query should return at least the order_id and status_id.  **4** for your select, get all the existing statuses.  when looping, if the status_id of the loop element == the status_id of the order_id being processed, add `selected = "selected"`.  **5** so 2 loops.  1: Workorder.  2: Status, inside loop 1.

Comment: this line: `$select_status = (1 == 1)? 'selected="selected"':'';` 1 is always equal to 1, so it will always set as selected. This `(1 == 1)` comparison should be something like `($Workorder->status_id ==  $status_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, get the statuses in an array to display select and compare the status_id with status_id of your workorder

```
   $status_sql = "SELECT status_id,status_text FROM STATUS";   // keep this query out of while, else will run n times //
    $result_status = $conn->query($status_sql);
    //$statuses = $result_status->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); //requires MySQL Native Driver (mysqlnd)
    $statuses = []; 
    while($status_row = $result_status->fetch_assoc()){
       $statuses[] = $status_row;
    }

    $workorder_sql = "SELECT first_name, status_id FROM wordorder LIMIT 0,30";  // or do a where id= if this is a single workorder page 
    $result_workorder = $conn->query($workorder_sql );
    while ($workorder_row = $result_workorder->fetch_assoc()) {

    //rest of code/logic/form fields
    ?>

    <select name="status" class="form-control input-default" required>
    <option selected disabled>Status</option>       
    <?php
    foreach($statuses as $status) {
    $status_id   = $status['status_id'];
    $status_name = $status['status_text'];
    //select status based on value in workorder row
    $select_status = ($workorder_row['status_id']  == $status['status_id'])? 'selected="selected"':'';
    echo '<option value="' . $status_id . '" '.$select_status.'>'.$status_name . '</option>';   
    }
    ?>
    </select>
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for the help @Manpreet, I have edited it a bit to grab a single workorder ID based on $_GET. It is giving me the error **Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all() in editorder.php:169 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in editorder.php on line 169**

line `$statuses = $result_status->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the support! I will ask my host to install mysqlnd.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are joining `ON w.status_id = s.status_id`, both of those values will be identical in `SELECT *, w.status_id as wid, s.status_id as sid`  (also, you aren't using your aliased column `$status_row['wid']`).

Look at the trouble that you are causing yourself by smashing together your assignment and comparison logic:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eOFBt))

```
$status_row['sid'] = $status_row['status_id'] = 3;
foreach (range(1, 5) as $status_id) {
    $select_status = ( $status_row['sid'] == $status_id  = $status_row['status_id'])? 'selected="selected"':'';
    var_dump($select_status);
}
```

Output:

```
string(19) "selected="selected""
string(19) "selected="selected""
string(19) "selected="selected""
string(19) "selected="selected""
string(19) "selected="selected""
```

You should just use this: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/iSulJ)

```
$select_status = $status_row['sid'] == $status_id ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
```

Output:

```
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
string(19) "selected="selected""
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
```